# Input field refresh issue

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element

I want to change the value of 3 input text at the same time.
The strange behaviour comes when I try to change the first input field (all of them are changed), then I change the second input field, again I would expect all of them changed, yet you can see the first one won't change.
It is like only "pristine" input fields will change.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/saavz2?file=my-element.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from

```
 <input type="text" data-id=${item.id} value=${this.state[item.id].value ?? ""} @input=${this.onInput} />
```

to

```
 <input type="text" data-id=${item.id} .value=${this.state[item.id].value ?? ""} @input=${this.onInput} />
```

[image]

See the [docs](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference) for **Property** binding.